# como cambiar el color de texto con canvas

Tags: canvas

Dibujo una cadena con canvas de esta forma:

```
    pdf.setFont("Helvetica", 16)
    # Dibujamos una cadena en la ubicación X,Y especificada
    pdf.drawString(230, 780, u"Contrato de CubanCloud")
```

Quiero saber como cambiarle el color que por defecto es negro.

Answer (score 3):

Aunque es algo muy básico, aqui tienes el código.

```js
var canvas= document.getElementById("miCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.font = "30px Comic Sans MS";
context.fillStyle = "red";
context.textAlign = "center";
context.fillText("Hello World", canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
```

```html
<canvas id="miCanvas" width="250px" height="250px"></canvas>
```